# How does Junos distinguish that route is learned in Layer 3 or Layer 2 VPN environment?

Tags: routing, juniper, layer2, juniper-junos, layer3

As I understand from [Understanding Junos OS Routing Tables](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/routing-tables-understanding.html) document, then `bgp.l3vpn.0`/`bgp.l3vpn-inet6.0` or `bgp.l2vpn.0` tables contain routes learned from other PE routers in Layer 3 or Layer 2 VPN environment respectively. Later, routes from those tables are copied to VRFs based on `route-distinguisher`. However, how does router distinguish that route is learned in Layer 3 or Layer 2 VPN environment so that it knows whether to put the route into `bgp.l3vpn.0` table or `bgp.l2vpn.0` table in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

When a route is distributed via MP-BGP, different route types are identified by their Address Family Identifier (AFI) and Subsequent Address Family Identifier (SAFI), attributes which are carried with the route between nodes.

For example L3VPN routes will have an AFI of 1 if they're IPv4, 2 if they're IPv6 and both will have a SAFI of 128 if they're Unicast routes.

L2VPN routes on the other hand will have an AFI of 25 and a SAFI of 65.

If you'd like some more detail, Juniper have a pretty good breakdown here:

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/usage-guidelines/routing-enabling-multiprotocol-bgp.html